# Multiple PHP dropdowns and getting the POSTed value from the array

Tags: php, html, post, drop-down-menu

I have ,  within a foreach , a dropdown:

```
`<select name="position[]">
<option value="1st">First</option>
<option value="2nd">Second</option>
<option value="3rd">Third</option>
</select>`
```

I need to be able to get the values from `position[]`when the form is posted

I had assumed it was `$_POST['position'][0]` , `$_POST['position'][1]` etc.

But that doesn't work .

Comment: only the selected items get posted

Comment: issue was related to another part of the code. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
foreach($array as $key=>$value){ ?>
<select name="position[<?php echo $key; ?>]">
<option value="1">First</option>
<option value="2">Second</option>
<option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

You should then be able to access each select like this:
`$_POST['position'][$key]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$test=$_POST['position'];
if ($test){
     foreach ($test as $t){
          echo 'You selected '.$t.'<br />';
     }
}
```

and also in select tag enable multiple selection by:

```
<select name="position[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included `multiple` in html code of select.

You should use

```
<select name="name[]" multiple size"5">
```